# Paypal in-app donation using Titanium

Tags: titanium, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, donations

I'm implementing a Paypal donation button in a charity app. I'm getting really (but really) confused from the tons of misleading informations and notions provided by Paypal's documentation. I'm looking for someone that can explain me what I need (and eventualy what I don't) to accomplish this task:

> A donation button in a view. When the user tap on it, it appears the
>   Paypal's login form. if the user authenticates properly, money are
>   transferred directly on the charity organization's account, otherway
>   an errow is thrown

[Here](https://raw.github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/master/paypal/mobile/android/example/simple.js) you can find the example provided by the authors of Titanium Paypal plugin, in which a button it's correctly instantiated and injected into the GUI. I guess that's the proper implementation I need (is it?)
In there, there're some concepts I miss:

1. **appID** - do I need one? Being this a not-advanced transation, it shouldn't be necessary, but...
2. **recipient** - should be the user for the charity organization account or, better said, *the user given as Classic API username for the charity organizzation account*. Is just specifying this is enough for addressing the transaction through their Paypal account?
3. **API Password, API Signature** - it seems they play no role in this transaction, isn't it?
4. **SandBox** - I know I can create fake users with a fake wallet. Then they can login in my app (as it's in PAYPAL_ENV_SANDBOX status) and perform fake operations. Am I missing something?

I used the code above, but results are not satisfying I can't never login as a user for paying.

Can anyone provide me a brief explanation of what I have to do?

Thanks

**EDIT 01/21/2014**

thanks to @andrew-angell I set my mind clear about above concepts, but I'm still freaking-out with the Titanium plugin you find in the GitHub's link above. In there, it seems there's no place to insert API credentials. Moreover, I'm still getting the "*Unexpected error, code -1*" if I try to use the button in SANDBOX environment (but it works in NONE environment). Docs and Examples are so straightforward that make me feel stupid for not getting them work.
I'll continue development in demo mode (NONE environment), but I wish I could do it in SANDBOX.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the SDK you're using is using Adaptive Payments (which it looks like it must be if it's calling for an App ID) then yes, you will need that in order to make live calls.
2. If you want the money to fall into 3rd party PayPal accounts you'll need to set them as the receiver in your payment and you'll need to utilize Preapproval profiles or Permissions to allow payer's to configure your app so it can make payments on their behalf.
3. You will always need your API username, password, and signature when working with the classic API's.
4. Yes, the sandbox is for testing your application without spending real money.

When you say the results are not satisfying, what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: I basically can't login,  no matter is a real or sandbox account

Comment: That's not very helpful.  What error are you getting?  Are you sure you're not attempting to login to the same account that you're trying to pay?

Comment: You're right, but even thrown error was helpful. It barely said "Unexpected error" with errorcode = -1.

Comment: That sounds like an app error as opposed to a PayPal login page error.  Again, that all comes down to the SDK you're using.  What we need to see are the actual API requests and responses getting generated.

Comment: Evoerithing is going fine if I whitch from Sandbox Environment to Demo, i.e. I use real user to login. Thus I guess the problem lies in my sandbox account, which are unverified and I'm unable to verify them

Comment: Try creating a new sandbox buyer account.  You should have the option to make them verified upon creation.

Comment: Excuse me, but I tried and it always asks me either a credit card or a bank account. Is there any way for verifying a sandbox account without provide such informations?

Comment: In my experience it fills that stuff in for you with bogus data that works when you create the account.  ARe you using the actual account creator or are you doing it manually through sandbox.paypal.com?

Comment: I'm doing through developers.paypal.com -> Applications -> sandbox. Searching in Google, they say you should access paypal in sandbox-version, login as a sandbox user and then verify your account AS YOU USED TO DO WITH YOUR REAL ACCOUNT, thus providing either bank account or cc number

Comment: You don't have to enter that stuff.  I just now did one and it worked fine.  Login to your account at developer.paypal.com and go to Applications -> Sandbox Accounts like you said.  Then click the Create Account button at the top, right.  The next form that comes up will ask you for account type, name, password, and it also has a "Bank verified account" option that is set to Yes by default.  As long as that's set to yes when you create it the sandbox account will be verified.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45656/discussion-between-balanza-and-andrew-angell)